# Corollary of Mori’s theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-varieties

Is there a direct proof of the corollary of Mori's theorem which says: If a projective complex manifold does not contain a rational curve then $ K_X $ is nef

Comment: What do you mean by a direct proof? The reference given to your previous question gives a direct proof.

Comment: I just want to use the absence of a rational curve to show that $ K_X $ is nef

Comment: Do you mean that you are wondering whether one can prove such a statement without appealing to Mori theorem?

Comment: The result of Mori that you quote is deep. I don't know if, more than 30 years later,  there is a proof that avoids some form of his original "bend and break" technique.  I assume that's what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes that's it @Donu Arapura